# How difficult is attaining EIT certification?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm currently filling out an application for the Massachusetts FE & EIT certification. Section 22 requests information regarding memberships to professional organizations. Unfortunately, I'm not a member of any and I'm afraid of leaving this section blank. Is anyone familiar with how leaving this section blank would impact my chances of getting certified?

Comment: It seems to me that you're either going to have to join an organization or leave the field blank.

Comment: Hi mikecat119, welcome to Engineering SE. The question you asked in the title is not quite the same as what you're asking in the body. Some people find the FE to be easy and others find it to be difficult; it's very subjective. If this isn't really what you're asking, please [edit] to make the title and body clear and consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not from Mass nor do I plan to go through the EIT process again.  Unless they state a requirement for you to complete X task, they should not be able to deny you access to the test based on not having completed the task.  Personally, I believe they are more compiling statistics with that information.

Joining professional organizations are a great thing and will help your business communications and to develop contacts.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I plan on joining the IEEE at the least.